# Change List View Field Order Using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom

I need to change the field order of a list view in SharePoint Online using JSOM or Rest. Appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried ? any sample code shows you did a bit of investigation on your side

Comment: To write a sample code the JSOM should support it. But I could not find any documentation on it. Found this one for CSOM though.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_members.aspx. If I can't find what to call, how am I going to write sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Check below thread for updating list view by JSOM.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript" language="ecmascript">

function runCode() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCollection = web.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Tasks");
        var viewCollection = list.get_views();
        var view = viewCollection.getByTitle("All Tasks");

        var query = '<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy>';

        view.set_viewQuery(query);
        view.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Tasks list ordered in descending alphabetic order.');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245986.aspx